# RL Circuit Analysis with 2 sources, how to find current of resistor?

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-analysis, resistors, inductor

I've been tackling some problems related to natural and step responses for RL & RC circuits, but I think I've hit a major roadblock for this RL circuit. I'm trying to find the time constant and current ***i3(t)***. While I'm certain that this type of circuit is first-order, I'm honestly stumped as to how the inductor, voltage source, and the current source change (or stay the same) for t<0, t=0, and t>0 conditions.
[image]

I'm certain that the equivalent resistance, **Req**, will be required for the time constant, so I attempted to do superposition (removing sources) at t=0 in order to find Req, knowing that it is relative to the way it is viewed from the inductor. Upon redrawing the circuit diagram (for t=0) and using thevenin theorem to solve for Req, I ended up with *Req = 1.59 ohms*. I'm not 100% certain whether this is correct, but I found that R3 is || to the series combination of (R4 + R5), followed by adding R2 to that result, then making that parallel to R1, leading to 1.59 ohms.
[image]
However, what I'm puzzled about is how to solve for the current **i3(t)** across the R3 resistor. My way of thinking tells me that ***i3(t)*** includes the steady states for both **i3(t=0)** and **i3(t= infinity)**, in which the first one is found by having the voltage source intact (and all of the resistors too),  but the inductor does short circuit at t<0 (right?). **i3(t=infinity)** should be able to be found for by short circuiting the inductor, replacing the voltage source with a wire, and having the current source remain intact. I have a good feeling that this is one way to find **i3(t)**, as the general equation for it is:

*i3(t) = i3(t=infinity) + [i3(t<0) - i3(t=infinity)]* e^(-t/tau)*

Are there perhaps potential gaps I have in my approach of solving for i3(t<0) and i3(t)?

Comment: R2 and R3 are **not** in parallel from the perspective of the inductor. You need to find the equivalent resistance that the inductor sees after the switch is closed.

Comment: So, if R2 and R3 aren't in parallel, then R2 (upon redrawing the circuit) must be parallel to (R1, R4, and R5), since they are all in series relative to R2 then? In that sense, R3 must be in series instead with [R2 || (R1 + R4 + R5)] right? When I took that approach, I ended up with a equivalent resistance of 6 ohms, which led to a small time constant of (L/Req) = 0.000167 ms. Isn't that perhaps quite small?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Also, considering that the equivalent resistance has been found to be higher than R3 series resistor, does the inductor no longer act as a short circuit, for t = 0+? Part of me thinks that with the current source being introduced into the circuit, both voltage/current sources change the dynamics of the inductor, or am I wrong in thinking this way?

Comment: No R1 is not in series with R4 and R5 for purposes of finding Req...one end of the inductor is connected between R1 and R4. The inductor does not act as a short circuit for t > 0, but the inductor current is continuous from t=0- to t=0+. I have no idea what you mean by "change the dynamics" of the inductor.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Wait, R1 isn't in series with R4/R5? How so? From what I see on the diagram, one end of the inductor is connected between R1 & R2, while the other end is between R3 & the voltage source (which is replaced by a wire). Am I misinterpreting that? As for the inductor current being continuous for both t<0 and t>0, does this suggest that iL(0-) = iL(0+) then? Oh, apologies for that remark, I'm just uncertain as to whether both the voltage and current sources affect the inductor current. So if I understand it right, is finding iL(t) no longer needed to solve for "i3" current?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Actually, I also wanted to ask as to why exactly does the inductor not act as a short circuit for t>0? Won't the final current be steady as t goes to infinity?

Comment: An inductor acts as a short circuit under **dc** conditions. For transient problems that usually implies when t < 0 or when t = infinity. Between those two time points the inductor current and voltage are changing, so it is no longer a dc situation. If the current is changing then the inductor voltage must be nonzero; hence not a short circuit.

Comment: When you deactivate V1 you get a connection from the right end of the inductor to the junction between R1 and R4. As the inductor is discharging some current will flow through it, so you can't say the the current through R1 and R4 must be the same, so they are not in series.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Ah, so the changing voltage & current for the inductor does indeed lead to the inductor being present within the circuit for that time interval. But then how would I even calculate the equivalent resistance for T = 0+ then if the inductor isn't a short circuit?  It's difficult to visualize how that would be illustrated for this kind of circuit. And if the right end of the inductor extends to the node between R1 & R4, then what happens to R3?

Comment: You calculate the equivalent circuit resistance by deactivating the sources and evaluating what the remaining resistance looks like **from the perspective of the inductor**. If you carefully examine how the resistors are connected you will see that R3 is in parallel with the series combination of R4 and R5.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Hmm, okay, so by that logic, R3 (being parallel to series combination of R4 & R5) would then be in series with (R1 being parallel to R2), right? Because we still have the left end of the inductor between R1 & R2?

Comment: R1 and R2 are not in parallel. The top end of R1 and the bottom end of R2 are not connected together.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson  Oh dear, you're right, I've been misinterpreting the nodes along each branch of the circuit that I didn't realize that R1, R2, and (R3|| (R4  + R5)) are all in series! All of which lead to the equivalent resistance. In that sense, that brings up the matter regarding both R3 and the inductor. From what I understand, it's possible that the current across R3 can be found by finding i3(t=0) and i3(t = 0+). However, because the inductor does not short circuit for t>0, would I have to find the current across the inductor as well too solve for i3(t)?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson  Actually, I retract my last statement about the equivalent resistance: it turns out that R1 is || to the [R2 + (R3|| (R4+R5))], upon further review. I turned out with an equivalent resistance of 1.59 ohms. Is this possibly correct?